# How do I get the default font(TTF) Windows Explorer is using?

Tags: windows, fonts, explorer

Countries that use non-English characters use fonts that support their language. Chinese Windows users use Chinese fonts, and Korean users use Hangul fonts.

What I want to do is display an arbitrary directory, but I don't know what string will go into that directory. It may be in English, or it may be a path including Chinese or Japanese.

In the program I'm writing, I need to read the ttf file that matches this path and print the text.

I think the problem can be solved if I can know the fonts in use and the languages ​​supported by the fonts in Windows Explorer installed on users' PCs.

Expressed in code, it would look like this.

```
FontInfo f = System.Control.Desktop.captionFont;

const char *ttfPath = f.ttfPath;
// ttfPath => C:\windows\Font\myFont.ttf

const char *language = f.design;
// ttfPath => "Korean" or "Thai"
```

Comment: The method I found is to look up the system font of C#, but with this method, the exact path of the ttf file cannot be known.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/how-to-use-systemfonts?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: The information I got using the above method is "[en-us, Malgun Gothic]", but the information I want is "malgun.ttf"(or "malgunbd.ttf" or "malgunsl.ttf" ).

Answer (score 0):

I write down how I found it. If you have a better way, please share.

1-Retrieve the system font family name:

```
    Button btncsharp = new Button();
btncsharp.Content = "SystemFonts";
btncsharp.Background = SystemColors.ControlDarkDarkBrush;
btncsharp.FontSize = SystemFonts.IconFontSize;
btncsharp.FontWeight = SystemFonts.MessageFontWeight;
btncsharp.FontFamily = SystemFonts.CaptionFontFamily;
cv1.Children.Add(btncsharp);
```

2-Retrieve **TTF** file name by font family name

**Registry :**

> **\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts**